# variable substitution in plpgsql(postgres) REINDEX query

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
--DROP FUNCTION tempscript();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tempscript()
  RETURNS integer AS
 $BODY$ 
DECLARE
my_index TEXT;
b integer;
BEGIN
my_index := 'example_index';
RAISE NOTICE '% ', my_index;
reindex index my_index; /* problem with this line , we are not able to pass local variable as paramenter*/

b :=2;
return b;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 
plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

SELECT * from tempscript();
```

please find my comment in the above code where exactly i am facing the problem.

please let me know the solution or workaround.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the user manual, you can only use variables where query parameters are permitted. That doesn't include identifiers and utility statements.

You need to use [the PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for dynamic SQL.

```
EXECUTE format('REINDEX %I', my_index);
```

Separately, if you need to automate `REINDEX`ing then you're almost certainly doing something else wrong. It should not be necessary in most situations. Maybe you've turned autovacuum down too far so it's failing to keep up?

If you're writing a function for a one-off, use a `DO` block so you don't have to create, execute, and drop the function.

Comment: @ Craig Ringer : Actually i am novice to plpgsql, currently working on one requirement to automate VACUUM and REINDEXING also but in my research i got to know that VACUUM wont work inside the function or multi line command. Any how i am able to reindex now with your answer. Thank you..

Comment: @SureshNamala You don't *have* to automate vacuum, and you shouldn't need to `REINDEX` if vacuum is working correctly. [Use autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html).

Comment: AutoVaccum is enabled in my databse.  I have a small doubt here, Lets say we have user defined INDEXES around 500 , still we need not to run Reindex manually. AutoVacuum itself is enough?? Please let me know

Comment: @SureshNamala Reduce `autovaccuum_cost_delay` and increase the vacuum worker count if required. See the link to the manual above. You should *not* need to reindex in normal operation. If you do so, you should generally set a `FILLFACTOR` of less than 100 on your indexes, otherwise you'll just waste disk doing page splits and relation extends after the `REINDEX`. If in doubt, let the system manage it, use autovacuum.